# Applescript - Apple Event Timed out

Tags: excel, applescript

I'm trying to open a very large excel file (*.xls) using applescript. The code is very simple, it looks like it is working, however after a few minutes I receive the following message:

Result:
error "Microsoft Excel got an error: AppleEvent timed out." number -1712

Any idea about how to solve it? BTW using the automator doesn't work either.

Here's my code

```
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        activate
        open "/Users/sergioguerra1/Desktop/Detektor/Etapa II/Reporte General.xls"
        delay 300
    end tell
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try wrapping the open command in a `with timeout` block.

eg.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    with timeout of 3600 seconds
        open "/Users/sergioguerra1/Desktop/Detektor/Etapa II/Reporte General.xls"
    end timeout
end tell
```

This will override Applescripts default timeout of 2 mins, giving it longer to finish executing that command.

More info [here in the AppleScript docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-130992).

Answer (score 3):

Conversely, if you are wanting to open your excel file/s without having to wait 2 minutes or longer ( eg 3600 secs) for a timeout to occur, then you may prefer to delibertely trigger the timeout *sooner*, and catch the error with "try" block.
I've found this problem occurs when I use the "linked tables" feature in excel, and the linked table is no longer accessable. Excel pops up a nasty dialog 1/2 way through the "open" command and just hangs till you type ESC twice ( or similar )  eg:

```
        try
            with timeout of 10 seconds
                open some_excel_File
            end timeout
        on error -- excel timeout probably due to linked tables

            -- if the file has "linked tables" we need to hit esc twice after opening it. 
            tell application "System Events"
                repeat 2 times
                    key code 53
                    delay 3
                end repeat
            end tell

        end try
```